# Django GET ?q="parameter" in get_queryset Class Based View

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

How do I access the "parameter" word in the url:

```
operations_product_search/?q=parameter
```

here:

class ASearchView(ListView):

```
...

def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    q = self.kwargs["q"]  <--- This is not working
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be `self.request.GET['q']`.

Answer (score 4):

I get query parameters using query_params

```
def get_queryset(self):
    q = self.request.query_params.get('q', None)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `get()`, you can avoid an exception if 'q=' is not present in the URL, by providing a fallback value (`None` here):

```
 def get_queryset(self):
     q = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
```